# How to: preview and print in my c# class library?

Tags: c#

I wrote a c# class that generate a html file and return this a string.

But I need to add a preview this document HTML (it can be in the browser), and print out option this document.

My code:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string HTMGenerator()
    {
        string html = "<p>test</p>";

        var xDocument = new XDocument(
            new XDocumentType("html", null, null, null),
            new XElement("html",
                new XElement("head"),
                new XElement("body"
                        XElement.Parse(html)),
                )
           );

        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
            Indent = true,
            IndentChars = "\t"
        };

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings))
            {
                xDocument.WriteTo(writer);
            }

            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not write `return xDocument.ToString()` - it does the same thing as your string writer code.

Comment: For viewing it--there's a web browser component.  Drop it on a form, feed it the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string filename = "Your FileName.html";
File.WriteAllText(filename, HTMGenerator());
Process.Start(filename);
```

---

Here's how I would write your code:

```
void Main()
{
    var filename ="Your File.html";
    var instance = new Class1();
    var document = instance.HTMGenerator();
    document.Save(filename);
    Process.Start(filename);
}

public class Class1
{
    public XDocument HTMGenerator()
    {
        string html = "<p>test</p>";

        var xDocument =
            new XDocument(
                new XDocumentType("html", null, null, null),
                new XElement(
                    "html",
                    new XElement("head"),
                    new XElement(
                        "body",
                        XElement.Parse(html))));

        return xDocument;
    }
}
```

Comment: where should I add it? to my .dll?

Comment: This should be added to where it logically makes sense.

Comment: can I add a preview to my .dll class file?
Is it only in the main program to refer to the string?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "add a preview to my .dll class file".

Comment: I understand that my dll (the first post) creates an html file and 'saves it to the string', which I can refer to in the main program?

so if it's true, I have a task: I must add a preview of this HTML file and print. \can I add this options to my .dll (first post)

Comment: @rayman22 - You can do anything you want. But I'd approach it by separating your concerns. Use my updated example as a suggestion.